# Can I use LGPLv3 version of Qt on Android iOS in my closed source application

Tags: software, distribution-terms

I want to use LGPLv3 version of Qt in my closed source application on iOS and Android. In order to give the users the possibility to re-link with another version of the Qt I can do the following:

1. Provide .apk for Android users so they can repackage with their own version of Qt.
2. Provide object files and XCode files for iOS users so they can re-link with their own version of Qt and deploy to their local devices.

Is it OK?

Comment: This would probably be more on-topic at [OpenSource.se].